# Discord trying to delete messages that are not there

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

i currently have a working discord bot which purges specified number of messages.

However,
I get a discord api error : unknown message

as if the user tries to `!purge 50` messsages, and there are only 20 messages in the channel, it will try and delete a message which is not there.

Im unsure how I could make it stop deleting messages if there are no more messages to delete.

Any help would be apriciated.

```
    execute(client, connection, message, args) {

    // check arg is a number, and that it is not greater than 100
    message.delete()
        .then(() => {
            // check if parameter for purge command is a number
            if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send(client.helpers.get('CreateEmptyEmbed').execute("Warning", client, false)
                .setTitle(`Invalid parameters for \`${this.name}\` command`)
                .setDescription(`You must enter a number between 1 and 100.`));
            const amountToDelete = Number(args[0], 10);
            // check if amount to delete is a whole number
            if (!Number.isInteger(amountToDelete)) return message.channel.send(client.helpers.get('CreateEmptyEmbed').execute("Warning", client, false)
                .setTitle(`Invalid parameters for \`${this.name}\``)
                .setDescription(`You must enter a whole number.`))
                .then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
            // check if amount to delete is bigger than 1
            if (amountToDelete < 1) return message.channel.send(client.helpers.get('CreateEmptyEmbed').execute("Warning", client, false)
                .setTitle(`Invalid parameters for \`${this.name}\``)
                .setDescription(`You must enter a number that is bigger than 1`))
                .then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
            if (amountToDelete > 100) return message.channel.bulkDelete(100) .then(message.channel.send(client.helpers.get('CreateEmptyEmbed').execute("Warning", client, false)
                .setTitle(`Invalid parameter value for ${this.name} `)
                .setDescription(`Deleted 100 messages! I can only delete a maximum of 100 messages at a time.`))
                .then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000})))
            message.channel.bulkDelete(amountToDelete)
                .then(message.channel.send(client.helpers.get('CreateEmptyEmbed').execute("Success", client, false)
                    .setTitle(`Successfully executed ${this.name}`)
                    .setDescription(`Successfully deleted ${amountToDelete} messages.`))
                    .then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })))
                .catch(err => {
                    if (err.toString().includes(`You can only bulk delete messages that are under 14 days old.`)) {
                        message.channel.send(client.helpers.get('CreateEmptyEmbed').execute("Warning", client, false)
                            .setTitle(`Error executing command`)
                            .setDescription(`You can only bulk delete messages that are under 14 days old.`))
                            .then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
                    } else {
                        message.channel.send(client.helpers.get('CreateEmptyEmbed').execute("Warning", client, false)
                            .setTitle(`Unknown error occured during ${this.name} command`)
                            .setDescription(`If this error continues please contact our support discord.`))
                            .then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
                        client.logdc.error(err);
                        client.logdc.error(`Error during ${this.name} command`);
                    }
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you possibly include a snippet of your code that performs the purging?

Comment: Yes of course, give me a second.

Comment: Why not get the number of total messages in the channel, check to see if the number to be purged is greater than it, and throw an error if so? [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)